# How to use socket_t (socket reference) to get ip and port in Network Kernel Extension of Mac OS

Tags: kernel-extension

I am writing the Socket filter in which most of call back functions for socket filtering(`struct sflt_filter`) have input parameter `socket_t so` as shown below:

```
   errno_t ( *sf_bind_func)(
   void *cookie,
   socket_t so,
   const struct sockaddr *to);
```

Need to get Port and IP from `socket_t so`.
Is anyone have the idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution in **OSx and iOS Kernel programming** Book.
function `sock_getsockname()` do the job. Find following code snippet:

```
    unsigned char addrStr[256];
    struct sockaddr_in addrLcl;
    sock_getsockname(so, (struct sockaddr *)&addrLcl, sizeof(addrLcl));
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addrLcl.sin_addr, (char *)addrStr, sizeof(addrStr));
    printf("SFWebSecBind() : <%s> Hex:<%X>", addrStr, ntohs(addrLcl.sin_port));
```